# Decrease the volume of sound played by AudioToolbox

Tags: iphone

If i play my sounds on the iPhone on max ringer volume it plays fine But when i reduce it to some extend ma AudioToolbox sounds are playing at the same volume But my AVAudioPlayer sounds are playing fine. Is there any way to decrease the volume of sounds played by AudioToolbox...

Answer (score 3):

From: [iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies/AudioandVideoTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH19-SW1)

The AudioServicesPlaySystemSound function lets you very simply play short sound files. The simplicity carries with it a few restrictions. Your sound files must be:

- Shorter than 30 seconds in duration
- In linear PCM or IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
  format Packaged in a .caf, .aif, or
  .wav file

In addition, when you use the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound function:

- Sounds play at the current system
  audio level, with no level control
  available
- Sounds play immediately
- Looping and stereo positioning are
  unavailable